# Key Value Store with public HTTP server

Tags: database, http, nosql

I am writing a service which will perform HTTP redirects. E.g.

```
GET /key/0CC175B9C0F1B6A831C399E269772661 HTTP/1.0
```

response

```
HTTP/1.0 301
Location: http://some-url/92EB5FFEE6AE2FEC3AD71C777531578F
```

This will be backed by a key-value store and will store a few million items.

Of course, the server part is simple to implement, but to reduce the number of services running I'm looking for a key-value store that will do the web serving for me.

Is there a key-value store that will such a public-facing web service?

Comment: A key-value-store to address how? From Java, PHP, Python…?

Comment: Preferably from Java, but I was hoping something matching the bill would have an HTTP interface.

Comment: Azure Storage Tables sounds like a match. Cheap as chips, fast as a rocket if partitioning is selected correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Remote Config could possibly do this. https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config

Answer (score 1):

If I were given this task I would turn to Openresty, you do not even need the whole shebang, just lua-nginx-redis driver for lua-nginx-module, under Ubuntu/Debian installing lua-nginx-redis will install all the nginx parts you need. And of course you'll need Redis. This [tutorial](https://openresty.org/en/dynamic-routing-based-on-redis.html) is extremely close - it does an internal redirect based on the user agent. Turning that into an external redirect based on the request URI is not hard.

It starts the process with `local key = ngx.var.http_user_agent` you'd need to change `local key = ngx.var.http_user_agent` to `local key = ngx.var.uri`. You can remove the `set $target '';` bit.

At the end instead of `ngx.var.target = host` just do `return ngx.redirect($target)`. You can remove `proxy_pass http://$target;` as it will never be reached.

I would be hard pressed to name a disadvantage of this solution. Openresty is well maintained and extremely fast. Redis is known to be of excellent quality, too. The amount of code / config to maintain is really as little as it can be.

Comment: Yeah, Redis was the first thing that came to my mind

Answer (score 0):

CouchDB - (key, document) rather than (key, value) but can still do what you want and supports Master/Master replication cluster too for high avail.